# Enlarging a probability space

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

The book I'm reading states:
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be some filtration on $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{Q})$ and $\eta$ a random variable such that

1. it is independent of $\mathbb{F}$ and
2. it has unit exponential law under $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. the pdf $f_\eta(x)=e^{-x}$)

The statement I'm confused about is as follows
"Of course $\eta$ [...] [is] given on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{Q})$ and thus a suitable enlargement of the underlying probability space may be required to produce $\eta$."

My question is:
Why does $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{Q})$ not suffice and how would such an enlargement look like?

Comment: Can you have a density on the rationals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is a finite set and $\mathbb Q$ is the uniform measure on it it is obvious that you cannot construct any continuous random variable on this space.
Consider $(\Omega, \mathcal G, \mathbb  Q) \times (\Omega', \mathcal G', \mathbb  Q')$ where $(\Omega', \mathcal G', \mathbb  Q')$  is any probability space on which there is an exponetnial (1) random variable $\xi$. Define $\eta (\omega, \omega')=\xi(\omega')$. Then $\eta$ has the required properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Do you happen to know if  there are conditions on a probability space for it to support $\exp(1)$ distributed random variables?

Comment: Any nice topological space ( a Polish space, for example) with  a non-atomic probability measure supports an exponential random variable.  A simple example of such a space is $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.  @Leonchino